# Conditional capturing in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to figure out how to write the following regex:

assume I can have two types of strings to check and find "value":

**string1**: `CONST1:CONST2:CONST3:value` and

**string2**: `CONST1:CONST2:CONST4:value-12345`

For **string1** this pattern would do

```
CONST1:CONST2:(CONST3|CONST4):(.*)
```

where I capture the second group. But I also need to handle the case when "value" is followed by the dash and some other value.
I tried it this way:

```
CONST1:CONST2:(CONST3|CONST4):(.*)(-.*)?
```

But then second group `(.*)` will capture everything in **string2**, including following dash + value2 (12345). Making it `(.*?)` won't work either, for string1 group2 would return empty String.

Can anyone point me in what direction should I look to find the solution? Should I dig into lookahead and lookbehind or there is a simpler solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use

(.*), but

([^\-]*)

to avoid - in the result.

It is often better to avoid the dot . but give a positive or negative list of allowed characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
^CONST1:CONST2:(CONST3|CONST4):([^\-\W]*)(-[^\W]+)?
```

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/vL4uG2/2

I tested the regex with the follow text:

> CONST1:CONST2:CONST3:hola
>
> CONST1:CONST2:CONST3:hola-43
>
> CONST1:CONST2:CONST4:hola
>
> CONST1:CONST2:CONST4:hola-12345